# pushing elements to an array of matrices

Tags: arrays, julia

suppose you want to have a array of matrices and iterate in
a for-loop and add in every loop a matrix to the array, afaik you could do it like this in julia:

```
V = Array{Array{Float64,2},1}  
for i=1:nlevels
    img = imgread("/path/img.png")
    push!(V, img) # append!(img) doesn't work too 
end

MethodError: no method matching append!(::Type{Array{Array{Float64,2},1}}, ::Array{Float64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  append!(!Matched::Array{T,1}, ::Any) at collections.jl:21
  append!(!Matched::CatIndices.BidirectionalVector{T}, ::Any) at ...
```

i get this error!

what am i doing wrong here!
How is there right way to achieve this in julia?

Comment: `V = Array{Array{Float64,2},1}` is missing a `()` at the end to construct the Array and not assign the Type to V (yeah, that happens ;) )

Comment: @Dan Getz thanks, it worked

Comment: @DanGetz Sorry, didn't see that you have already resolved. +1

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal It's all good!

Comment: Should still accept the answer, so this question doesn't remain "unanswered" in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `()` is what you missed!

Have a look

```
julia> V = Array{Array{Float64,2},1}
Array{Array{Float64,2},1}

julia> typeof(V)
DataType

julia> V = Array{Array{Float64,2},1}()
0-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}

julia> typeof(V)
Array{Array{Float64,2},1}
```